# How to setup connection to MySql database with gitlab CI/CD

Tags: mysql, django, gitlab

I'm trying to set up automatic testing of django project using CI/CD gitlab. The problem is, I can't connect to the Mysql database in any way.

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```yaml
services:
  - mysql:5.7

variables:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "db_name"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "dbpass"
      MYSQL_USER: "username"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "dbpass"
      

stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  before_script:
  - apt update -qy && apt-get install -qqy --no-install-recommends default-mysql-client
  - mysql --user=$MYSQL_USER --password=$MYSQL_PASSWORD --database=$MYSQL_DATABASE --host=$MYSQL_HOST --execute="SHOW DATABASES; ALTER USER '$MYSQL_USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '$MYSQL_PASSWORD'"
  script:
  - apt update -qy
  - apt install python3 python3-pip virtualenvwrapper -qy
  - virtualenv --python=python3 venv/
  - source venv/bin/activate
  - pwd
  - pip install -r requirement.txt
  - python manage.py test apps
```

With this file configuration, I get  error

```
 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

What have I tried to do

add to  `mysql` script tcp connection unstead socket

```bash
mysql --protocol=TCP --user=$MYSQL_USER --password=$MYSQL_PASSWORD --database=$MYSQL_DATABASE --host=$MYSQL_HOST --execute="SHOW DATABASES; ALTER USER '$MYSQL_USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '$MYSQL_PASSWORD'"
```

And in this case I got

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (99)
```

How do I set up properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use service name as database hostname. In this case `MYSQL_HOST` should be `mysql`.

You can see example on [Gitlab page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/mysql.html#use-mysql-with-the-docker-executor) and read about [how services are linked to the job](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#how-services-are-linked-to-the-job)

Comment: thanks for the comment. After I add `MYSQL_HOST: "mysql"`  I got `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'userlocal'@'172.17.0.3' (using password: YES)")`

Comment: should the  **variable** specified in yml match the actual data specified in the .env file of the project?

Comment: Yes, django should connect to test database using credentials defined for mysql service.

Answer (score 10):

There can be multiple reasons for your issue:

- Incorrect MySQL version.

  - Solution: Use `mysql:5.7` instead of `mysql:latest`
- MySQL host is missing.

  - Solution: add `MYSQL_HOST` in the `variables` with the hostname of the MySQL server. (Should be `mysql` when using `mysql:5.7` in `services` key)
- Django uses different credentials of DB.

  - Solution: check that the credentials in the `variables` section of your `.gitlab-ci.yml` and compare against Django's `settings.py`. They should be the same.
- MySQL client not installed.

  - Solution: install the `mysql-client` in the script section and check if it is able to connect.

Here is a sample `script` that installs MySQL client and connects to the database in a debian based image (or a `python:latest` image):

```yaml
script:
  - apt-get update && apt-get install -y git curl libmcrypt-dev default-mysql-
  - mysql --version
  - sleep 20
  - echo "SHOW tables;"| mysql -u root -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -h "${MYSQL_HOST}" "${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
```

Here is a complete and valid example of using MySQL 5.7 as a service and a `python` image with `mysql-client` installed successfully connecting to the MySQL database:

```yaml
stages:
  - test

variables:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: "db_name"
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "dbpass"
  MYSQL_USER: "username"
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: "dbpass"
  MYSQL_HOST: mysql

test:
  image: python:latest
  stage: test
  services:
    - mysql:5.7
  script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y git curl libmcrypt-dev default-mysql-client
    - mysql --version
    - sleep 20
    - echo "SHOW tables;" | mysql -u root -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -h "${MYSQL_HOST}" "${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
    - echo "Database host is '${MYSQL_HOST}'"
```

Comment: I fixed the example a bit and made sure it works using the following public project: https://gitlab.com/gableroux/gitlab-ci-mysql-service-example

Answer (score 0):

I see there is an accepted answer but with `mysql 8.0` and `python3:buster` some things broke. The `Python Debian` images ship with `mariadb` and it is not easy to set up the standard `mysql-client` packages, resulting in the error:

"django.db.utils.OperationalError: 2059, “Authentication plugin..."

I got a working YAML below, using Ubuntu as the base image and `mysql 8.0` as a service. You could either use the root user in both the `.gitlab-ci` and the `test_settings` or give the MYSQL user the privileges to create new databases and alter existing ones.

The initial `MYSQL_DB _USER` and `_PASS` variables can be set in `Gitlab` under `Settings -> CI/CD` -> Variables.

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
variables:
    # "When using a service (e.g. mysql) in the GitLab CI that needs environtment variables
    # to run, only variables defined in .gitlab-ci.yml are passed to the service and
    # variables defined in GitLab GUI are unavailable."
    # https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/30178
    # DJANGO_CONFIG: "test"
    MYSQL_DATABASE: $MYSQL_DB
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_PASS
    MYSQL_USER: $MYSQL_USER
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_PASS
    # -- In your django settings file for the test environment you could put:
    # DATABASES = {
    #     'default': {
    #         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    #         'NAME': os.environ.get('MYSQL_DATABASE'),
    #       'USER':  os.environ.get('MYSQL_USER'),
    #       'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('MYSQL_PASSWORD'),
    #       'HOST': 'mysql',
    #       'PORT': '3306',
    #         'CONN_MAX_AGE':60,
    #         },
    # }

    # -- You could us '--settings' to specify a custom settings file on the command line
    # -- below or use an environment variable to trigger an include in your settings:
    #   if os.environ.get('DJANGO_CONFIG')=='test':
    #       from .settings_test import *  # or specific overrides
    #


default:
    image: ubuntu:20.04

    # -- Pick zero or more services to be used on all builds.
    # -- Only needed when using a docker container to run your tests in.
    # -- Check out: http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#what-is-a-service
    services:
    - mysql:8.0

    # This folder is cached between builds
    # http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#cache
    # cache:
    #   paths:
    #     - ~/.cache/pip/

    before_script:
    - echo -e "Using Database $MYSQL_DB with $MYSQL_USER"
    - apt --assume-yes update
    - apt --assume-yes install apt-utils
    - apt --assume-yes install net-tools python3.8 python3-pip mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
    # - apt --assume-yes upgrade
    - pip3 install -r requirements.txt

djangotests:
    script:
    # -- The MYSQL user gets only permissions for MYSQL_DB and therefor cant create a test_db.
    - echo "GRANT ALL on *.* to '${MYSQL_USER}';"| mysql -u root --password="${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}" -h mysql
    # -- use python3 explicitly. see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python/3
    - python3 manage.py test


migrations:
    script:
    - python3 manage.py makemigrations
    - python3 manage.py makemigrations myapp
    - python3 manage.py migrate
    - python3 manage.py check
```

Answer (score 0):

We have created a docker image for this:

```yaml
variables:
  MARIADB_USER: test_user
  MARIADB_PASSWORD: password
  MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root@password
  MARIADB_DATABASE: my_db

django-tests:
  image: orbisk/django-test:3.11
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: mariadb:10
      alias: maria
  script:
    - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
    # The MYSQL user only gets permissions for MYSQL_DB, so Django can't create a test database.
    - echo "GRANT ALL on *.* to '$MARIADB_USER';"| mysql -u root --password="$MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD" -h maria
    - python3 manage.py test
```

See here (https://github.com/singularit-de/django-test) for further information